# Converter data com JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, data

Como faço para converter a data nesse tipo `02 Ago 2017` para `02/08/2017`?

Estou usando o `vuejs-datepicker` e ao selecionar ele vem nesse formato, e na documentação diz para fazer assim:

```
customFormatter(date) {
    return moment(date).format('dd MMM yyyy');
}
```

Mas usando eu não quero usar o Moment. Como posso fazer?

Comment: O momento é a melhor lib para date que tem no mercado e você não quer usar

Comment: @Otto nao, nao quero usar, quero usar JS Puro

Comment: `02 Ago 2017` para `02/07/2017`? O correto não seria `02/08/2017`? E o seu formato será sempre esse, com a abreviação do mês em pt?

Comment: @LucasCosta o 7 foi um erro na hora que fui digitar, e sim, esta configurado para PT, mas posso configurar para EN, e sempre sera abreviado sim.

Comment: Acho que a resposta do @DNick se encaixa, talvez com algum ajuste para trocar de posição o mês com o dia..mas voce poderia comentar nas respostas que já existem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você pode criar uma instância do tipo *Date* no JavaScript e utilizar o método [`toLocaleDateString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString#Checking_for_support_for_locales_and_options_arguments).

Capture a data em formato americano:

```
let data = new Date(Date.parse('Aug 4, 2017'));
```

Para exibir data no formato local:

```
console.log(data.toLocaleDateString()) //"04/08/2017"
```

Para exibir no formato americano:

```
console.log(data.toLocaleDateString('en-US'))
```

Comment: Funcionou, valeu :D, me tira uma duvida, caso eu queira converter para o formato americano, como faria? (Só por curiosidade)

Comment: `console.log(data.toLocaleDateString('en-US'))`